# Smallest cost traversal of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, traversal

How do you compute the smallest cost traversal of an integer array using steps and jumps, while also counting the first and last element of the array? A step is moving to the next immediate value in the array e.g. array[currentIndex + 1], and a jump is moving two spots e.g. array[currentIndex + 2]. I have the following function which I want to return the minimum sum started, it adds the first and last elements to the sum, but I'm stuck on the middle values of the array.

```
An example of this would be {2, 10, 4, 14, 44, 28, 16, 18} -> 66
which would add indexes 0, 2, 3, 5, and 7.
```

====

```
public int Cost(int[] board)
{
    int sum = board[0];
    int index = 0;
    while (index < board.Length)
    {
        //Add the final array value to the sum
        if (index + 1 == board.length)
        {
            sum += board[index];
            break;
        }
        //Add other values here

        index++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: How would you solve it with a pencil and paper?  You need an algorithm (step-by-step process) before you even write the first line of code.  What is your proposed algorithm?

Comment: @mellamokb My first thought was to see if a jump or a step was smaller then add it to the sum and move to which ever action's corresponding index and repeat.

Comment: That's an excellent idea.  So to make it more "mechanical", 1) look at the next two numbers (step vs jump).  2) compare which one is smaller  3) take the smaller one, add it your sum and make that you next starting point.  Can you write code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    public int Cost(int[] board)
    {
        int[] cost = new int[board.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < board.Length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                cost[i] = board[0];
            } else if (i == 1) {
                cost[i] = board[1] + cost[0];
            } else {
                cost[i] = board[i] + Math.Min(cost[i - 1], cost[i - 2]);
            }
        }
        return cost[board.Length - 1];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this does what I want to do. I kept getting caught up on OutOfBound errors but this works.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
public int Cost(int[] board, int step = 1)
{
    if (board == null) return -1;
    if (board.Length == 0) return 0;

    // always add first and last index (if its not the first)
    int sum = board[0];

    if (board.Length > 1) sum += board[board.Length - 1];

    // assumes step is > 0
    for (int i = step; i < (board.Length - 1); i += step)
    {
        sum += board[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This allows for step to be a parameter.  Maybe now you want to step either 1 or 2 away from the start.  Maybe later you want to step 5 spots away.

Comment: This is good but, I need to be able to determine within the function whether to step 1 or 2 spaces in the array. This seems limited to what ever size step is passed in with step.